# Migrate to androidx on older version of android studio i.e. 3.1.2?

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, androidx

As mentioned in the question, I need to migrate to androidx support library and currently, I use 27.1.1 version of the library and on Android Studio 3.1.2 in refactor section `Migrate App to App compat` appears.

So how should I proceed to move towards androidx version from here?

```
 implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportLibVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:preference-v7:$supportLibVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:$supportLibVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:$supportLibVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportLibVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportLibVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportLibVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:$supportLibVersion"

ext {
supportLibVersion = '27.1.1'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to manually change each dependency from support library to androidX & after that you'll have to change all the imports in your project!

I recommend upgrading Android Studio, as it will do all the heavy lifting...

More info. - https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/hello-world-androidx.html?m=1

Comment: Refactor is available in Android Studio Canary 14 and as its canary version, so it's quite unstable at many places.

Comment: @SahajRana it does provide a backup project option before refactoring.